# Integrating non-continuous density function

Tags: probability-theory

How does one handle integrations where there are points that are not continuous. For example to calculate $E(X)$, where the density of X is 
$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x^{2} & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}$

Then $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdF(x)=\int_0^1 2x^{3} dx$, Is the last equality justified? Since the density is not continuous at x=1?

Comment: If the set of discontinuities is finite, the value of the integral is unaffected. In fact, the same is true if the set of discontinuities is countably infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no short answer. Modern probabilities are defined with tools from measure theory and Lebesgue integration, which allow you to define the integral of a much larger class of class of functions than just continuous functions (like Riemann integration does). (Actually, it is a bit more complicated than that, you have to verify that your function is integrable, but this is going too far here)

These functions are called measurable, and your function $f$ just happens to be measurable and integrable (in the Lebesgue meaning).

I guess you will have to study measure theory if you want to really understand these things.

Comment: Okay fair enough..but am I fine if I use the last equality? Or did I miss something..

Comment: Sorry about that, I guess I should have answered this more precisely. Yes, your equality is entirely true. As $f$ is $0$ on $\mathbb{R} - [0,1]$, the integral on all $\mathbb{R}$ just happens to be equal to the one on $[0,1]$.

In an intuitive way, the discontinuity at $x = 1$ does not really matter because "a point has $0$ length". So integration just "ignores" the discontinuity at $1$. Though, this is everything but a proof.